# How do I change my code to read all types of delimited files? It currently only reads csv files and then compares them

Tags: java

csv1

ID, Name
1, Kris
2, Josh
3, Sam
4, Peter

csv2
ID, Name
1, Kris
2, Ralph
3, Stan
4, Bob

```
package com.company;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Diff {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

        ArrayList<String> values1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> values2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        File sheet1 = new File("C:\\Users\\Krisesh.Kanchi\\Documents\\csv1.csv");
        File sheet2 = new File("C:\\Users\\Krisesh.Kanchi\\Documents\\csv2.csv");

        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(sheet1);
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(sheet2);

        scanner1.nextLine();
        while (scanner1.hasNextLine()) {
             values1.add(scanner1.nextLine().split(",")[1]);
    }

    scanner2.nextLine();
    while (scanner2.hasNextLine()) {
        values2.add(scanner2.nextLine().split(",")[1]);
    }

    int iteration = 0;

    System.out.printf("%-6s%-6s%-6s\n","Sheet-1", "    ", "Sheet-2");
    System.out.println();

    for (String value : values1) {
        if(values1.get(iteration).compareToIgnoreCase(values2.get(iteration)) != 0) {
            System.out.printf("%-7s%-6s%-7s\n",values1.get(iteration), " --> ", values2.get(iteration));
        }
        iteration++;
    }
}
```

}

this code can determine the difference between two csv files accurately but fails to make this comparison when the delimiter is changed. I want to be able to run any files through this program of the same nature such as tab delimited, pipe delimited, etc.

Comment: Hi Kris, you seem to be on the right track. You just have to keep it clear that you can change the character you are using to split to any delimiter you want to cover. I'll not focus on where you can optimize your code. But you need to define a way to map the delimiter to each file type or to inform which ones do you want to use here, before the next step.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A distinct non-answer: you don't do that. Unless you have **a lot** of time at hand.

You see: parsing arbitrary CSV files is **much** harder than you think it is. A self-written CSV parser works for exactly those input files you initially test it with. As soon as you test it with some *valid* CSV from another source, chances are that it will fail. (and yes: been there, done that)

It starts with a very simple thing: you can't just **split** on your delimiter. You see:

```
"a string, with a comma","another string, another comma"
```

is valid CSV content. So: you have to carefully look out for quotes.

The next thing is of course the ability to handle various specific types automatically, like date/time parsing, and so on.

Thus: if you need a CSV parser for a real world system, consider using one of the existing library solution, like [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). Don't re-invent the wheel unless there are good reasons to do so.

(Yes, learning how to do it might be a good reason. Being in need for a CSV parser is not, as other people wrote one for you ages ago.)

Having said that: your current code is **hard coding** all the things that could/should be **parameters** on the command line:

- the file name(s) to parse
- the delimiter to use

So, to answer the question asked: do **not** put such parameters directly into the code. Allow the user to **set** them dynamically, for example by passing them on the command line.

But again: those are exactly the kind of things that a real world tool offers you for free.